# How to convert german number to english using Numeral.js

Tags: javascript, numeral.js

I have used below mentioned code for converting German number to English no using Numeral.js

```
var numeral = require('numeral');
var numeralDE = require('numeral/languages/es');
numeralDE.delimiters.thousands = '.';
numeral.language('es', numeralDE);
numeral.language('es');

console.log(numeral(0,50).format('0,0.00'));
```

and it will return me the output

```
0,00
```

how I can convert it into **0,50** to **0.50**

Comment: does `numeral` actually take 2 arguments?

Comment: `es` is German?

Comment: Try `numeral/languages/de` (though Spanish numbers aren't that different)